# Select sport results ordering by medals

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table:

```
sport country place
ski  swe 1
ski  nor 2
ski  rus 3
luge swe 1
luge usa 2
luge ger 3
bob  nor 1
bob  rus 2
bob  ger 3
```

where place is 1 for gold, 2 for silver, 3 for bronze

Now the normal displying scenario is a list of countries, first max gold, then silver then bronze. for that exampe it would be:

```
swe g:2 s:0 b:0 sum:2
rus g:0 s:1 b:1 sum:2
usa g:0 s:1 b:0 sum:1
nor g:0 s:0 b:2 sum:2
```

what would be SQL query to get list of countries ordering by that way?

regards

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
   country,
   sum(case when place = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as gold,
   sum(case when place = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as silver,
   sum(case when place = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as bronce,
   count(*) as allmedals
from tab
group by country
```

For ordering the result you might do

```
order by sum(4 - place) desc -- weighted medals
```

Comment: thanks, that works... only the ordering is complex.. as you have to specify the ordering for the countries for example with same SUM(gold).. there they should be ordered by silver.. etc..

Comment: Then simply change the order to **ORDER BY gold DESC, silver DESC, bronce DESC**

Comment: Many thanks!!!!! That saved me a lot of time and I learned new things about SQL queries!!

Answer (score 0):

using multiple ordering is a key: here is query. Thanks to user:dnoeth

```
select
   country,
   sum(case when place = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as gold,
   sum(case when place = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as silver,
   sum(case when place = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as bronce,
   count(*) as allmedals
from tab
group by country ORDER BY gold DESC, silver DESC, bronce DESC
```