# SQL statemest getting data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have two tables:
tab1 has column:

```
[country]
SWE
GER
USA
```

and another one, tab2, with columns "country" and "medals":

```
[country] [medals]
SWE        1
GER        2
```

I would like to have a list of countries with number of medals. So I do

```
 SELECT t2.country, t2.medals FROM tab2 as t2, tab1 as t2 WHERE t1.county = t2.country

 output:
 swe 1
 ger 2
```

ok, I have a list with 2 countries, because "USA" is not at tab2. But I want to have it in my output with "medals" set to 0. How to do this?

UPDATE.
 For that simple query it works fine. But my query is more complex. I tried to do it in the same way, but and it doesn't work for me. I am trying to calculate gold, silver and bronce medals by countries (field "place" 1-gold, 2-gold, 3-silver). see also this topic:
[Select sport results ordering by medals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485431/select-sport-results-ordering-by-medals)

here is my query:

```
SELECT c.country_id as c_id,
c.image_id as i_id,
c.string_id as s_id,
COALESCE(sum(case when r.place = 1 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as gold,
COALESCE(sum(case when r.place = 2 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as silver,
COALESCE(sum(case when r.place = 3 then 1 else 0 end), 0) as bronce
FROM countries as c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN results as r ON c.country_id = r.country 
WHERE r.type = 'mytype' 
group by r.country
ORDER BY gold DESC, silver DESC, bronce DESC, c.country_id DESC"
```

Comment: Use explicit JOIN syntax instead of this (implicit) comma-join rubbish. Then the answer will be obvious.

Comment: What does not work with that query?

Comment: it shows only row where both tables has a country(like SWE, or USA) but if there no entry for the country in table "results" it should shows a row with 0 medals.. but it doesn't. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `outer join` in order to also join the missing countries. Once you've done that, you can use `coalesce` to replace the resulting `null` with `0`.

```
SELECT          tab2.country, COALESCE(tab2.medals , 0) AS medals
FROM            tab2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tab1 ON tab1.county = tab2.country
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT t2.country, isnull(t2.medals,0) 
FROM tab2 as t2
LEFT JOIN tabl1 t1 on t1.country=t2.country
```

Comment: thank you, it works so far, I updated my answer with more complex query that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join), and then use [coalesce](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) to replace the NULL values from the missing records with zero:

```
SELECT tab1.country,
       coalesce(tab2.medals, 0)
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.country = tab2.country
```

Comment: thank you, it works so far, I updated my answer with more complex query that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an outer join in order to also join the missing countries. Once you've done that, you can use coalesce(filedName,value) or IFNULL(fieldName,value) to replace the resulting null with 0.
  tips:IFNULL()is a function in mySql, ISNULL is a function in sqlserver,nvl is a function in Oracle ,my English is not good ,so I copy some text from @Mureinik  ,I hope that can help you.

```
SELECT t1.contry, IFNULL(t2.medals,0)  FROM contry AS t1 LEFT JOIN medals AS t2 ON t1.contry = t2.contry
```

or

```
SELECT t1.contry, COALESCE(t2.medals,0)  FROM contry AS t1 LEFT JOIN medals AS t2 ON t1.contry = t2.contry
```